# Смена A записей для большого количества доменов

Tags: php, linux, веб-программирование, dns

К нашему web-сервису многие клиенты привязывают свои домены.

Выглядит этот так.
Есть раздел сервиса **example.com/client184**

```
DNS example.com A 1.1.1.1
```

Человек покупает домен допустим **viktor.ru** и прописывает у него

```
DNS viktor.ru A 1.1.1.1
```

Наш сервер получая запрос к **viktor.ru** выводит содержимое страницы **example.com/client184**

Как оптимизировать систему, что бы при смене A-записи DNS example.com не пришлось обзванивать всех клиентов и помогать им изменять DNS записи своих доменов?

Comment: использовать CNAME ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В таких случаях нужно использовать запись CNAME для ведомого домена указывая там корневой домен проекта, в данном случае example.com.

```
DNS viktor.ru CNAME example.com

DNS @ example.com A 1.1.1.1
DNS lk.example.com A 2.2.2.2
```

Т.е. все клиенты должны вместо A-записи для своего домена добавить запись CNAME. В таком случае при изменении записей на example.com автоматически сменятся записи на всех ведомых доменах у которых есть CNAME на example.com

И при входе на viktor.ru запрос будет отправляться по DNS правилам example.com

Answer (score 0):

Была у меня такая задача, реализовал её через `CNAME`.

Так как клиенту не важно что к чему привязывать, то мы даем клиенту наш поддомен, в вашем случае `example.com/client184` и говорим вот к нему привяжите ваш новый домен, в вашем случае `viktor.ru`.

Клиент привязывает и как бы не менялся ваш IP, разделы клиента всегда будут доступны.

Comment: А разве можно в CNAME ввести адрес страницы сайта?
И разве CNAME не осуществит переадресацию с изменением адреса в адресной строке? Т.е. клиент вводит в браузере viktor.ru и браузер меняет адрес в адресной строке на example.com?

Comment: @Nastya Нет, адрес страницы нельзя конечно. в CNAME указывается просто example.com. зато это не IP адрес и все клиенты пойдут по тому ip который указан в example.com

Comment: @Nastya нет, там только домен нужно, но чтобы клиент всегда имел доступ к своему сервису и вам не нужно было его тревожить, то думаю можно сделать в виде поддоменов эти сервисы и тогда через cname это реализовать, потому что если привязываться к IP потом начнется что клиент почту не читает, был в отпуске, болел, его сайт не был доступен

Comment: При указании у всех клиентов вместо A записи записи CNAME example.com не будет ли происходить автоматический редирект в браузере. При вводе адреса viktor.ru у него не будет в адресной строке меняться адрес на example.com?

Comment: @Nastya нет, вы же делаете это не на стороне сервера, а на уровне DNS

Comment: @Nastya и адрес меняться не будет

Comment: Т.е. я правиьно поняла, что добавление CNAME просто говорит о том, что нужно использовать записи домена указанного в CNAME, а не производить переадресацию на этот адрес в браузере?

Comment: @Nastya да, работает так же как и A запись по сути, только можно указывать домен, ну это на сколько я из своего опыта знаю, в тонкостях думаю чем то они отличаются, но у нас так работают сайты и проблем нет уже 2 года, пользователи не знают оригинальный наш поддомен, видят только домен клиента и думают что это его сайт, а не просто сервис.

Comment: А при добавлении записи A для поддомена example.com этот поддомен сработает при обращении к этому поддомену через viktor.ru?
Например у viktor.ru кроме записи CNAME example.com нет других записей. А у example.com есть A запись ru.example.com 2.2.2.2 сработает ли это при входе на ru.viktor.ru?

Comment: @Nastya если они у вас будут динамически вы пишите у себя А запись *.example.com чтобы ловить все поддомены, а на сервере уже выводите информацию в зависимости от поддомена, и тогда vikror.ru попадает под ваше правило *.example.com и идет на тот IP что уже вы указали

Comment: @Nastya как вы напишите - так и отработает, это DNS же, куда сказали - туда и пошлет.